# how can i fill an array from a text file using a delimitor?

Tags: php, ip

I am writing a program in php to check ip's , now I know that are easier ways to do so, but i want to do it my way. This is what i have written so far

```
<?php
 if($_POST) {
$file=fopen("names.txt","a") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$ipadres=fopen("ip.txt","a") or exit("Unable to open file!");

$name = $_POST['username'];
$file_content = $name. "|";
$ipadres_content = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . "|";
$iparray = array();
$i=0;
fputs($file,$file_content);
fputs($ipadres,$ipadres_content);

while(!feof($ipadres))
 {
    $iparray = explode("|", fgets($file));
 }
fclose($file);
fclose($ipadres);
}


?>
```

As you can see i tried using a while loop to put the ip-adresses in to an array to check. but when I try to run it it just keeps running until it finally crashes in to this error= Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.Oh and yes i tried to put the max crash limit up a bit but still no sign of succes.

Comment: wow php has a max crash limit? :D

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is faulty:

```
while(!feof($ipadres))
{
    $iparray = explode("|", fgets($file));
}
```

You're checking for `feof($ipadres)` and using `fgets($file)`

i.e. you keep checking end of file with file pointer `$ipadres` but reading from file pointer `$file` which will cause **infinite loop** and program will crash eventually.

Probably you meant:

```
while(!feof($ipadres)) {
    $iparray = explode("|", fgets($ipadres));
}
```

OR else use [file function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) which returns all the lines of a file in an array.

Comment: oh yeah well thats a stupid mistake :p. So i changed it but still keeps crashing.

Comment: but better is to use file function which saves a lot of code.

Comment: i tried to put everything on a different line but that didnt really work out as planned so i tried to do it with the delimitor.